# RequestFactory service inheritance on the client in GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

GWT 2.4 brings service inheritance on the client ([issue 6234](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6234), [issue 6035](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6035)).

I've been waiting for this future for a long time, as it saves a lot of duplicated code on the client. I've started implementing it, but so for with mixed success.

This is my code:

```
public interface BaseEntityRequest<T>
{
    Request<Void> put(T entity);
    Request<List<T>> getAllOrderBy(String propertyName);
    Request<List<T>> getRangeAndFilter(int limit,int offset, QueryInfoProxy queryInfo);
}

@Service(value = EgdDao.class, locator = DaoServiceLocator.class)
public interface EgdRequest extends RequestContext, BaseEntityRequest<EgdProxy>
{
    Request<Void> exportToExcel(QueryInfoProxy queryInfo, String userName);
}
```

So far `getAllOrderBy` and `getRangeAndFilter` work fine, but `put(T entity)` does not.

I get the following error in the console:

```
[ERROR] Unexpected error
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

and this gets returned in the receiver onFailure ServerFailure message:

```
Error 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /gwtRequest. Reason:
INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

The only cause, that I can see, for the `put` method not to work, when the others do, is that it uses the generic parameter T. When I move the `put` method in the `EgdRequest` interface (using `EgdProxy` as a parameter instead of T) it starts to work, so I know my server code is fine.

Does anybody have any idea how to implement this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey. How did You solve this. I know that a lot time passed, but maybe You could help me? I am trying to make generic proxy and context for the client side code.

Comment: Hi, sorry, but I was never actually able to fix the issue. I donțt know if the bug has been solved in the meantime or not, as I no longer use GWT:

Comment: I've also gave up on request factory. I use rest now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a GWT bug. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6794

Comment: Thanks! Hope it gets fixed soon :).