# GWT Bug in RequestFactory client-side service inheritance

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have problem in creating a generic RequestContext that has common methods such as persist, update, remove and other Request classes extend this class. I got following exception :

```
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ReportableException: Could not locate RequestContext operation
```

after some googling found this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6794)
and also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433910/requestfactory-service-inheritance-on-the-client-in-gwt-2-4).
 and I think it's not resolved yet.
is there anyway to do this that I need not to repeat every method in all Request classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when a bug has been reported and is still open, then yes it's still not resolved, and as such, the workaround still applies. So no, there's no other way currently than re-declaring the methods in the subinterfaces.